# "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" versus "SharePoint Server Publishing"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, publishing-site, enterprise-wiki

I am working on a SP 2013 enterprise wiki site collection. by defualt the site collection feature named "`SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure`" will be active. but the site feature "`SharePoint Server Publishing`" will be deactivated. so my question is do i need to active the site feature "`SharePoint server publishing` " if i already active the "`SharePoint server publishing infrastructure`" site collection feature baring in mind that i do not have any subsite inside the enterprise wiki site collection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature** provides publishing functionality at the **site collection level**, Provides centralized libraries, content types, master pages and page layouts and enables page scheduling and other publishing functionality for a site collection.

**SharePoint Server Publishing feature** provides publishing functionality at the **site level**. Create a Web page library as well as supporting libraries to create and publish pages based on page layouts.

To read the what publishing features will be enabled when acitivting both or any of above features.

[Publishing features overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628963%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

This is true for 2013 as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but even if I do not active any of these features i can still access the master pages and page layout using SP designer, and i can also created my own master pages as well,, so i can not understand what do u mean by "the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature ..... Provides centralized libraries, content types, master pages  ..." as i will get master pages and page layout without having to activate these features???

Comment: did you read the technet article, it explains in details what extra you will get.

Comment: master page are basics but when you enable publishing feature then it give you extra functionality, controls and options.

Comment: one thing i have observe during my testing is that if you enable these features then you will not be able to save the site as template. but i did a test on the following; where i enable these 2 features at the site collection level, then i created a new subsite where i did NOT enable the "SP server publishing" feature at the new sub site level, and i was able to save the subsite as template even if its site collection is having these 2 features enabled ?? is this valid , i mean to save a subsite as a template while its site collection have these 2 features activated

Comment: if you enable the Publishing feature at Site collection level but subsite is team without publishing feature then yes you can save that subsite as template.

Comment: so that why i do not want to activate the "sp server publishing" at the sub-sites levels as i might need to save these sub-sites as templates in the future.. Second point I have noted also now if i only enable the "The SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature" at the site collection level, then the site collection and all its subsites will have a "Navigation" option link under their look and feel site setting , which is a very helpful feature, and no need to enable the publishing feature at the subsite level to get the Navigation link enabled...

Comment: thanks a lot for the link it really help me in understanding the benefits. now i have a site collection of type Team site where i have previously enabled the "publishing infrastrucre " site collection feature at the site collection level, the i have deactivate it ,, but still all the new contents, and libraries and options are there ,, so does this mean that even if i deactivate the publishing infrastructure SC feature , i can still benefit from it ???

Comment: No, if you deactivate it then all extra should removed.

Comment: actually it will only remove the libraries from the site content that does not have items, while libraries such as "workflow tasks", "Reusable content" will stay inside the site content even after deactivating the "publishing infrastructure" site collection feature. now regarding the permission all the user groups except the "translation manager" will stay after deactivating the feature. so user groups such as approver, designer, restricted reader, that were added after activating the feature will not be removed, after deactivation the feature !!